# Как задать выход из программы?

Tags: c++, формы

В приложении есть кнопка выход? Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на нее программа завершалась?

Comment: Ваш вопрос не выглядит полным. Какая ос? Какое API для GUI используете? Какая стреда программирования?

Comment: Есть два варианта - стандарный выход, и принудительный. 1) Стандартный - выйти из главной (main) функции (но если есть ждучие потоки, долгоиграющие деструкторы может возникнуть другой вариант). 2. Принудительный (не рекомендуется, но иногда нужен) - получить PID процесса, и отпратить terminate/kill своему процессу.

Comment: @Unick я подозреваю это вин формс

Comment: Приведите листинги кода как создаете окно, и какие библитеки подключаете.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос и это работа с  вин форм из под с++, то код будет приблизительно таким

```
  void button1_Click( Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e )
   {
      Application::Exit();
   }
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms157894(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1)